# Custom content element is not rendered in front-end

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Need help with a custom content element that is not being rendered.
This is my typoscript:

```
tt_content.cat_button = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.cat_button {
    template = FILE
    template.file = EXT:so_product/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentELements/CategoryButton.html
    layoutRootPath = EXT:so_product/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

Even if I misspell `CategoryButton.html`, there won't be an error message. So how will I know if the correct template is found?

If I remove rows `template` and `template.file`, I get message "Oops, no template found..."

My template only contains `<p>Test</p>`. Do I need sections and layout too?

This is the guide I used: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sitepackage/CustomContentElements/Index.html

No errors in log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo:

`ContentELements` -> `ContentElements`

Also bug in TYPO3 that didn't display error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your typoscript is simply wrong.

Check the TSRef http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

```
tt_content.cat_button = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.cat_button {
   file = EXT:so_product/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentELements/CategoryButton.html
}
```

Comment: No, it was a typo ><. `ContentELements` -> `ContentElements`. But the above TS works.